# Store evey calculation as item in Array

Tags: java, arraylist

I have made a console calculator that the user input the numbers and the operation in one line like this;

> 5 + 5

after pressing enter it will show the result like this;

> Result: 5 + 5 = 10

I am trying to **store every complete result to an array so I can print or list them when the user pressed (L)** but I could not succeed as **my code always stores the last calculation**.
I want the calculations printed when the user press L like this:

> Operation: L 
> Previous Calculations:
> 5 + 5 = 100
> 4 * 5 = 20

Here is my code and I thank you in advance.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        do {
            System.out.print("**********************************************\n"
                    + "Enter L to list previous calculations.\nEnter Q to exit.\n"
                    + "**********************************************\n"
                    + "Operation: ");

            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            String input = scan.nextLine();
            String[] operation = input.split(" ");

            if (input.length() < 5) {
                if (input.equals("q")) {
                    System.out.print("\n\n**********************************************\n"
                            + "ByeBye\n"
                            + "**********************************************\n");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                if (input.equals("l")) {
                    System.out.println("\n\nPrevious Calculations:\n");
                    continue;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("\n\nWrong Operation!!!");
                    continue;

                }
            }

            int first_number = Integer.parseInt(operation[0]);
            int second_number = Integer.parseInt(operation[2]);

            int outcome = 0;

            boolean wrong_operation = false;
            String operator = operation[1];

            switch (operator) {
                case "+":
                    outcome = first_number + second_number;
                    break;
                case "-":
                    outcome = first_number - second_number;
                    break;
                case "*":
                    outcome = first_number * second_number;
                    break;
                case "/":
                    outcome = first_number / second_number;
                    break;
                default:
                    wrong_operation = true;

            }

            String answer;
            String array_item;

            if (wrong_operation) {
                System.out.println("\n\nWrong Operation!!! " + "(" + operator + ")");
            } else {
                answer = String.valueOf(outcome);
                array_item = input + " = " + answer;
                System.out.println("\n\nResult: " + array_item);
                char[] myArray = array_item.toCharArray();
                System.out.println(myArray);
            }

        } while (true);

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare a list to store the previous calculations before de `do` declaration, like this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> previousCalculations = new ArrayList<>(); // Declare list
        do {
            System.out.print("**********************************************\n"
                    + "Enter L to list previous calculations.\nEnter Q to exit.\n"
                    + "**********************************************\n"
                    + "Operation: ");
        ...
        ...
```

Then store the results after you show the answer

```
                answer = String.valueOf(outcome);
                array_item = input + " = " + answer;
                System.out.println("\n\nResult: " + array_item);

                previousCalculations.add(array_item); // Store results
```

And finally print the previous calculations when the option is selected:

```
                if (input.equals("l")) {
                    System.out.println("\n\nPrevious Calculations:");

                    // Print the previous calculations
                    for(String calc : previousCalculations) {
                        System.out.println(calc);
                    }
                    continue;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("\n\nWrong Operation!!!");
                    continue;

                }
```